# rake generate_secret_token error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, redmine

I am trying to install redmine in my windows 7.
I have installed and executed railsinstaller-2.2.3.exe.

When I tried to run following command

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

am getting below error

```
could not find gem 'rails<=3.2.19> x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine
```

What is this error mean? am new to this? please let me know if anybody knows this

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to use VirtualBox with linux environment. Otherwise use Bitnami windows installer for redmine https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer

Comment: This is not answer to my question

Comment: bundle exec rake generate_secret_token

Comment: Ok, I'v downloaded this rails installer for windows and redmine source to check what problem you have. First of all you need to understand that rails installer for windows install rails v4.1(no matter what documentation say).

Comment: So you need to run 'command prompt with rails', cd into you redmine dir and perform 'bundle install' which will install proper gems and rails. After that you will be able to run commands against rails 3.2(which redmine uses) with command: bundle exec YOUR_COMMAND_GOES_HERE     Cheers~